# Frozen C#/.NET when debugging a program with multiple dynamically-generated assemblies

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2019, clr, coreclr

We have a program that utilizes System.Emit's ability to generate types on the fly. As time goes by, the number of types we are generating reaches over tens of thousands. This revealed a performance issue where TypeBuilder.DefineType gets exponentially slower for every type added to the main assembly - which is undesirable.

One year ago, I have made effort to find a way around this. The idea is to place the generated types in separate assemblies. So instead of having 20k generated types in a single assembly, they are now spread over a number of assemblies. This gave us really good performance results. So far so good.

I used the simplex method to find a solution for optimal performance. This involved a test that generates types and makes them randomly dependent on each other across all assemblies/modules. The result was to create 3 modules per assembly, and to gradually grow the number of types stored in each module with the following equation:

- const int MODULES_PER_ASSEMBLY = 3;
- _typesPerModule = (int)((0.003225993f * _currentStep + 222.721f) / MODULES_PER_ASSEMBLY);

The above significantly lowers the amount of time spent in creating types, at the expense of huge memory overhead for each assembly created (roughly 10MB per assembly). However since we deemed this performance increase to be very attractive (gave us about 800% speed ups for our tests and runs), we have adopted this strategy.

A very strange behaviour relating to the Visual Studio debugger has risen. Ever since we adopted the above method in type generation, we have been encountering strange program freeze that caused it to use 0% CPU, while also freezing debugger. It is impossible to pause the program because the debugger simply hangs. However, it seems if we ran the program without the debugger attached, it works just as normal.

We made efforts in looking into the issue:

- We know this problem only manifests itself in debug mode with the debugger attached. If we run a stand-alone (i.e. ctrl+F5), it works as normal.
- The problem manifests itself randomly and random times of the program execution. Therefore we believe this might be a thread-related issue.
- We created process dump of the hanged process and did some analysis for any potential thread deadlocks. However nothing jumped out so far.
- We constrained the number of module per assembly to 1, by doing MODULES_PER_ASSEMBLY = 1. The problem still shows, indicating it relates to the nature of having multiple dynamic assemblies.
- By reducing the number of dynamic assemblies generated to 1, we got rid of this issue entirely, but with the performance slow down.

Following the above, we only know that the issue is introduced by having multiple assemblies and having the debugger on, but we don't know why.

So I wanted to ask if the Visual Studio debugger supports this kind of usage, and if there are any known potential instability with debugging programs that generates and use multiple dynamic assemblies. I have not seen a question with a background such as ours, so I'm unsure how common practice this is.

Specs on the environment I am using if it's helpful at all:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019
- .NET Framework 4.7.2
- 32GB RAM

Comment: If you have 0% CPU and everything is frozen, might there be a deadlock somewhere?

Comment: I think so too, it must be a thread deadlock somewhere